# Redux toolkit: How to call another action from thunk(createAsyncThunk)

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to call an action from a thunk created by createAsyncThunk.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const searchAction = createAsyncThunk(
  'search/searchJoubun',
  (request, thunkAPI) => {
    thunkAPI.dispatch(setIsLoading(true)) // <- This doesn't trigger the setIsLoading action
    // Call an API to search
  },
);

const searchSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'search',
  initialState: {
    isLoading: false,
    searchResult: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    setIsLoading(state, payload) {
      state.isLoading = payload.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(searchAction.fulfilled, state => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        // Do something
      })
      .addCase(searchAction.rejected, state => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        // Do something
      });
  },
});

export default searchSlice;
export const { setIsLoading } = searchSlice.actions;
```

Inside `searchAction()`, I would like to mutate `isLoading` to `true`, before calling the API. Whet `searchAction()` is executed, it calls the API but the `setIsLoading` is not triggered.

Should I not call `setIsLoading` from the thunk and dispatch `searchAction()` and `setIsLoading()` separately from a component?

##### Versions

- react-redux v7.2.5
- reduxjs/toolkit v1.6.1
- jest v27.0.6
- ts-jest v27.0.5

Comment: Try to declare searchAction after you declaring setIsLoading

Comment: Error occurs: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'searchAction' before initialization

Comment: Genrally: why do you want to do that? Usually we recommend againstdispatching many actions at once and there is already the `searchAction.pending` action being dispatched for exactly the purpose of what you want to achieve here.

Comment: @phry  Yes, I can do `searchAction.pending`. I don't know but I thought I could dispatch many actions and it's okay...

Comment: It generally is, but here you need `searchAction` to define `searchSlice` and need `searchSlice` to define `searchAction` so it's a hen-and-egg problem.
Generally we recommend to avoid many actions sequentially: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#avoid-dispatching-many-actions-sequentially